# Angular 2+ (7) Shallow test of a nested component

Tags: angular, input, automated-tests, angular7, angular-test

Ok, so I have a component for which I am writing some tests. In this component I have another component that has an Input:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'navigator',
  templateUrl: './navigator.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./navigator.component.scss'],
})
export class Navigator{

    @Input()
    public myobject: InputClass;
}
```

The InputClass is a simple object:

```
export class InputClass{
    public id: string;
    public Name: any;

    constructor(id: string) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

And in the main component I have the corresponding property:

```
@Component({
      selector: 'main-component',
      templateUrl: './mainComponent.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./mainComponent.component.scss'],
    })
    export class MainComponent{

         public myObject: InputClass;
    }
```

The mainComponent template:

```
 <navigator class="container" [myobject] = "myObject">
 </navigator>
```

Now I want to test that, if I set some value in the myObject property of the mainComponent, then check if the @Input value in navigator has received the value:

```
it('set the input in navigator',() => {
    let testobj: InputClass;
    testobj = {
        id: '1',
        componentName: 'SomeValue',
    };

    component.myObject= testobj;
    fixture.detectChanges();

    el = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('navigator'));

    // For test and debug purposes
    let test = el.nativeElement.attributes['ng-reflect-myobject'];

    expect(test.value).toBe(testobj);
});
```

I tried this before with another input but of type string, and when I set the value it worked like a charm, but here it fails, and when I debug it with chrome I get that the value of the attribute is [object Object]:

**The test result**

[image: Test result]

**The debug information**

[image: Debug]

Now what I think is happening is that I am getting a stringified version
of the object (because in js it is the default conversion from an object to string, right?). If that is the case how can I get the object from the input?

Answer (score 0):

You could'nt validate the navigator HTML rendered content?

I believe searching form a string in the renderedHTML would be a lot simpler, and acchieve the same test effect.

In the Angular Testing Docs they use the textContent property to do that: [Angular Testing - By CSS](https://angular.io/guide/testing#bycss)